# Finding first marriage of William Franklin Greenfield of Patterson, Caldwell Co., North Carolina, USA?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, marriage-records, north-carolina

I have been researching my Great-Grandfather, William Franklin Greenfield for many years and this is the timeline I have for him:

- William was born around 1854 or so.
- William was married to my Great-Grandmother, whose name was Martisha Cook Greenfield.

  - Martisha died in child birth on, March 20, 1914 when my Grandmother, Mary Lula Cook Greenfield Salyers was born.
  - Martisha was 25 and William was 55 or so.
- William was originally from Patterson, Caldwell Co. N.C. His father's name was William J. Greenfield.

Is there a marriage certificate for William Franklin Greenfield for his first wife, who lived in Caldwell Co. N.C.?

---

My mother always said that William Franklin Greenfield was married before and had two daughters who ran away and was never heard from again.

My Grandmother, Mary Lula was adopted by Caroline Cook, who was Martisha's aunt. Caroline was married before and had one son. His name was Robert Greenfield. According to his birth certificate his fathers name is listed as W. W. Greenfield.

W.W. Greenfield may be the great-grandfather that I'm looking for.  Caroline is listed in the 1900 Census under Finly Greenfield's household with her son, Robert. I do not know however who she was married to. I do not know what happened to William after Martisha died.

Also there is a rumor in our family that one of William's kin was found as a baby in a field in Greenfield and that's why they gave him the last name.

I have already searched these places: Myheritage, Familysearch, Geni, Wikitree, Usgenweb.

William Franklin Greenfield is listed as father on my grandmother's birth certificate. W.F.'s father is listed as W. J. Greenfield and his mother as Rosa Greenfield:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  I edited your question to remove some conversational aspects that are not directly related to the question.  If you wish to introduce yourself then your [user card](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/4219/juanita-ellen-snider-sutphin) is the place where you should feel free to do that.

Comment: The way our focussed Q&A works, which is different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites, means that we need to try and identify that it is the death record for your great grandfather William Franklin Greenfield that is the primary focus of your search at the moment.  Can you confirm that by using the [edit] button beneath your question, please?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  Asking "do you have any information on the Greenfields" is much too broad -- someone could write a book on that.  Rather than looking for others who might already know your area, G&FH.SE's focus is on how we can build the skills to find the answer to specific problems you can solve.  Did the whole story come down to you via your mom?  Do you have any other sources yet besides the 1900 Census?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to find William's birth, marriage and death records, as well as census records.  Unless you already have it, I think you should focus on the marriage record first (because that helps link him to your grandmother, and thus to you) but if you already have any of the others can you provide details/links of/to their sources, please?

Comment: The timeline suggests that the marriage occurred around 1915 - based on him being born about 1860 and being about 55 when married - but what evidence do you have for either?  If you can include a source for his birth, and/or another for his age on perhaps one or more census records it would be helpful.

Comment: I have my Grandmother's Birth Certificate and William Franklin age is stated as being 55. My Grandmother was born in March 1914. They had to have been married before that.

Comment: @Juanita I know it's been a while since you asked this but I hope someone can come up with an answer for you. I'm still a little bit unclear when you say you're looking for William's first marriage – was his first marriage to Martisha, or was he was married before that?

Comment: @JuanitaEllenSniderSutphin Be a little careful when you make assumptions about when a couple was married, based on the birth dates of their children.  If there are older children you didn't know about you could be way off -- and sometimes people didn't have the means or opportunity to marry until after some of their children were born.